# trust relationship between Active Directory and SQL Server

Tags: sql, active-directory

If I have Active Directory with users in it.  And I have a SQL Server with other users in it.  The SQL Server holds the users in a table.  With the passwords encrypted.

Is there a way to sync or set up a trust relationship between the 2?
For users that are in both systems?

thanks

Comment: What do you want to do? Allow AD users to log in using AD while other users log in using existing system? Or create AD accounts for the SQL Users?